# Quokka won't start on VSCode, not sure how to fix my node

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, quokka.js

Quokka is throwing the errors "spawn node ENOENT", "Can not start node.js(node), make sure your system has node.js installed", and "You may use the "node" setting to configure the location of node."

I'm new to VSCode and Quokka and have no clue how to fix this or to even find config.json

Comment: do you have [node](https://nodejs.org/en/)? you can run `node --version` in a terminal check

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have node installed and you are either on mac or linux, run `which node` and add that path to `~/.quokka/config.json`

```
{
  ...
  "node": "<node_path>"
}
```

I use nvm so mine looks like this:

```
{
  ...
  "node": "~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.10.0/bin/node"
}
```